# if and broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

In a BroadcastReceiver class I've this code but I don't understand why first notify does not run. If I remove if cycle, alarmmanager runs perfectly. Also values are ok (I've a toast that show me it). Is a "if" problem?

```
CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
    notify = prefs.getString("notify", "");

if (CheckboxPreference){
        if (notify.equals("1")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
        }
        if (notify.equals("2")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
        }
        if (notify.equals("3")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, middleAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
    }
    }
```

Comment: there looks to be nothing wrong with your code. you might, however, try `if (notify.trim().equals(...))` or have you verified somehow that you're getting into the `if()` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should complete your `if`'s with `else`. Log errors if you hit the `else`'s

Also check all the conditions in your `if`'s, eg what is the value of `notify` and CheckBoxPreference. This should help you to debug the code yourself.

```
   if (CheckboxPreference){
        if (notify.equals("1")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
        }

        else if (notify.equals("2")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
        }
        else if (notify.equals("3")){
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, morningAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, middleAlarm);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, eveningAlarm);
        }
        else {
           // Log something
        }
    }  
    else {
       // Log CheckBoxPref false

    }
```